# Should content node structure align with its semantic URL

Tags: aem, jcr

I would like to know what is best practice in regards to structuring content in AEM. Or JCR for that matter.

Lets say I have 1000 articles. And these articles have categories. The user would find them via semantic URLs like this

http://domain/category/subcategory/title

I could create a tree node structure in AEM to reflect exactly that

[image]

I get the feeling this is not maintainable, and if there are changes (like dropping a category out), then content needs to be moved manually somewhere else.

Is there a rule of thumb as to how to plan/structure these websites?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your content structure looks pretty efficient to me.  Not quite sure what u meant by manually moving content somewhere else. If you want to drop a category, why would you want to move it somewhere else?

Btw, there is no specific rule of thumb to designing content hierarchy, just few nitbits you need to be aware off. Content design depends a lot on the business scenario, data growth and how efficiently you can model the structure keeping the following points in mind:

- Scalability and maintainability
- Caching: dispatcher rules
- Search Query costs: Flat structure would affect query efficiency
- Meaningful content organization
- ACL's: permission cascade hierarchically

This link [here](https://docs.adobe.com/docs/en/cq/5-6-1/developing/chap_data_modelling.html) will probably shed more light

Comment: thanks, in regards to structure changes. Lets say I have the 1k articles split evenly between categories A B C and D. One day the client comes and tell us "you know what, I want all category D articles distributed among A B and C, delete category D". Thats why I'm not sure if I should go that way or just go flat and use tags

Comment: hmm, with the /cat/subcat/article structure, moving article pages across different categories will definitely have an impact on the points mentioned above (URL, ACLs, caching rules, query cost, etc). A flat structure with all the article pages tagged would work, but how would sling map the resources to http://domain/category/subcategory/title URL efficiently in that case?. Looking at your business case, got to think of a more efficient way.